# (.htaccess) how to mod_rewrite a tilde user site to subfolder within same site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory, tilde

I have been working this issue for several nights with no luck. I'm trying to Rewrite web requests using (.htaccess)
from: cobweb.seas.gwu.edu/~mpnl
to: cobweb.seas.gwu.edu/~mpnl/joomla

My latest (.htaccess) file is below:

```
# turn on Rewrite
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cobweb.seas.gwu.edu/~mpnl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/joomla/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /joomla/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ joomla/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the URI path with the %{HTTP_HOST} var, only the host. You'll need to either include the `~mpnl` part as a rewrite base or as part of the request URI:

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove the "/~mpnl" from the end of this line, add a [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cobweb.seas.gwu.edu$ [NC]
# add a "/~mpnl" to here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~mpnl/joomla/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# remove the leading slash before "joomla"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ joomla/$1 [L]

# add a condition to this:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~mpnl/joomla/
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ joomla/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your suggested (.htaccess) file without success- still getting the same 500 Internal Server error. I double-checked and mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.I used textedit to edit the file, ensured the file was saved for unix, and ansi encoding. Also tried various permissions. I should mentioned I saved the (.htaccess) file to the root of public_html.

Answer (score 0):

To [rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) requests with a [`UserDir`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/public_html.html) in the URI, you have to set a [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase):

```
RewriteBase /~mpnl/
```